# Read .properties file in java with new line characters in values

Tags: java, regex, properties, dictionary

I defined a .properties file with properties like this

```
A=Hello World this is a dummy text

B=Bye Bye World I am leaving to mars
```

I am able to read it properly after loading resource from input stream and display them good.

Now i want to define these properties like this

```
A= Hello World 
   this is a 
   dummy text

B= Bye Bye World 
   I am leaving to 
   mars
```

However it don't load it as expected

```
A as Hello World
```

and

```
B as Bye Bye World.
```

Do i have to go by myself defining a regex and read this and fill it in a map.

Or is there any way default available in `Properties.java`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a `\n` and then end the line with the "continuation" character: `\`

```
A=Hello World\n \
this is a\n \
dummy text
```

Note that leading whitespace is trimmed when loading the Properties file. So you need to add that to the end of the previous line if you need indented lines:

```
A=Hello World\n   \
this is a\n    \
dummy text
```

Comment: yup this is working. But this continuation character in the end isn't adding beauty to the file and is painful to add it at each line end. I believe for that i need regex of my own. Or is there any escape this as well ?

Comment: regex to read key=Value without continuation character and new lines allowed. break till you get other key=Value pattern

Comment: @Javanator: no, you don't need that. The `Properties` class will handle that automatically.

Comment: thats what i said will define a class that will find the pattern and fills it in the map. same like properties class. Then i can define properties file cleanly . I hope i am making sense

Comment: Properties i believe is sub class to map itself. so the load is doing nothing reading the input stream. looking for key value pattern and filling it in.

Comment: I will wait for some other comments or more answers for better ways to do this. If didn't get any. Will accept this answer in the end. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Javanator: sorry I don't understand. The `Properties` class **will** handle everything for you. The values returned by `getProperty()` will contain the linefeeds. You don't have to do anything.  Try it out if you don't believe me.

Comment: will the properties class will handle everything if i don't use the continuation character. ?

Comment: @Javanator: why don't you try it.

Comment: nop. if i remove the continuation character it isn't giving the value after the \n or the values in the next lines.