# Spring Batch JDBCCursorItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

Is there any better way to load sql from file system to inject in JDBCCursorItemReader.
I want to load sql query from files instead of hardcoding in the configuration file.

```xml
//spring bean    
<bean id="jdbcReader" class="com.sample.DatabaseReader">
    <property name="sql" value="query.sql"/>
</bean>
```

and then i extended JDBCCursorItemReader

```java
//extended cursoritemreader
class DatabaseReader extends JDBCCursorItemReader {

    //Overriden method
    @Override
    public void setSql(String fileName) {
        //file
        File f = new File(fileName);
        //read file from given path
        String query = FileCopyUtils.copyToString(f);
        //pass the query
        super.setSQL(query);

    }
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with the way you have done? this proper way.

Comment: you're right to suspect you shouldn't have to extend the itemReader to do this kind of thing. how about http://stackoverflow.com/a/25557773/217324 ? if you want named parameter support, then that's a little more involved, i do it with a FactoryBean that returns a namedParameterPreparedStatementSetter.

Comment: @NathanHughes - Could u pls explain why i shouldn't override the method

Comment: @Karthik: you can do it that way, it's not terrible. there are other alternatives, though. (and in some setups file system access is not that easy, it's better to read the file as a resource)

Answer (score 3):

Use Spring's `PropertyPlaceHolder` to inject the SQL directly into the reader (no need to extend our reader for this).  An example would look like this:

```
 <bean id="jdbcItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="myRowMapper>
    <property name="sql" value="${batch.sql}"/>
</bean>
```

As long as you have a `PropertiesPlaceholderConfigurer` configured that points to the properties file that holds the `batch.sql` property, you should be good to go.

Comment: If my queries are pretty long then its difficult to maintain in properties file.

Comment: What other type of file do you propose to use to store them in?

Comment: I thought of having my queries in .sql files and load them dynamically.

Comment: Beyond the fact that there is a `key=` in front of each line…what's the difference?

Comment: @Michael: i think the big difference is you can't have newlines in a query in a properties file. that's why i linked to an answer I posted on a similar question suggesting using xml cdata for this.

Comment: Actually you can, you just need to format it correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433144/read-properties-file-in-java-with-new-line-characters-in-values